# Flutter: I want to update an unspecified amount of data in a firebase document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I want to update an unspecified amount of data in a firebase document,  I would like to know to use List.map or other methods to update the data all at once.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      DocumentReference documentReference =
          collectionReference.doc('usera');
      DocumentSnapshot ysnapshot = await transaction.get(documentReference);

      for (int i = 0; i < profileList.length; i++) {
        transaction.update(
            documentReference, {profileList[i].value: profileList[i].data});
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [List.forEach](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html).

> **forEach method**
>
> void forEach(
> void f(
> E element
> )
> )
>
> Applies the function f to each element of this collection in iteration order.
>
> [Source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html)

You can update this loop:

```dart
for (int i = 0; i < profileList.length; i++) {
  transaction.update(documentReference, {profileList[i].value: profileList[i].data});
}
```

to this:

```dart
profileList.forEach((profile) {
   transaction.update(documentReference, {profile.value: profileList.data});
});
```